# Best practice for WPF application user settings storage?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm refactoring a WPF application and dealing with cleaning up storage of settings.  I've re-written most to use the application's settings (Properties.Settings.Default) and this technically is working right now it seems to generate rather ugly paths in the %appdata% folder such as:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Company_Name_With_Underscores\program.exe_Url_xs3vufrvyvfeg4xv01dvlt54k5g2xzfr\3.0.1.0\

These also then result in a new version number folder for each version that don't get cleaned up ever unless apparently I manually do so via file io functions.

Other programs don't seem to follow this format, including Microsoft programs, so I'm under the impression this seems like one of those 'technically the best way but not practical so nobody uses' solutions.  Is this the case or am I missing something to make this more practical?

I ask mainly because I can foresee issues if we ever have to direct a customer to one of these folders to check or send us a file from there.

I'm using .NET 4.0 right now.

Comment: IMHO, for any simple program and for many non-simple programs, the Designer Settings are still appropriate. Your observations about encoded directory names and unpurged files are correct, but IMHO not relevant. It's been a long time since having even a few dozen tiny XML files lying around useless actually mattered. I agree, it's offensive from an aesthetic point of view. But it has no practical impact. It's unlikely you'll ever need a customer to interact with the file directly, but if so it's easy enough to identify the most recent by timestamp.

Comment: In any case, any question that asks for "best practice" is 99.94% guaranteed to be off-topic as "Primarily opinion based". Lacking a clear, actionable problem statement in the question, that is IMHO the case here.